# How to sequence through sets of numbers in shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I would like to sequence through a set of numbers.

A simple example is sequence through 2 numbers, then sleep for 5 seconds before proceeding to the next 2.

For example:
1
2
(sleeping for 5 seconds)
3
4
(sleeping for 5 seconds)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `for` loop in bash:

```
for ((i=1; i<10; i+=2)); do echo $i $((i+1)); sleep 5; done

1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as well, using the modulo operator `%`:

```
declare -i max_value=10 # set it whatever you want
for ((i = 1; i < $max_value; i++)); do
  printf "Number is: $i\n"
  [[ $(( $i % 2 )) == 0 ]] && printf "Sleeping\n" && sleep 5  # sleep when the number is even
  # do whatever...
done
```

Output:

```
Number is: 1
Number is: 2
Sleeping
Number is: 3
Number is: 4
Sleeping
Number is: 5
Number is: 6
Sleeping
Number is: 7
Number is: 8
Sleeping
Number is: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If your set of numbers is not a simple set of ascending integers like [anubhava's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41902667/6232717), you can do similar things.

For example, if your sequence is in a list, `list.txt`:

```
declare -ai a=($(<list.txt));  ## Read the sequence from list.txt into a
declare -i i l=${#a[@]};
for ((i=0; i<l; i+=2)); do
    echo ${a[i]} ${a[i+1]};
    sleep 5;
done;
```

If your sequence's numbers are in a string, like `s='1,2,3,4,5,6,4,32,25,4,6,4'`, you could do `declare -ai a=(${s//,/ })` to fill `a` with your numbers.